# Oracle: Select From a Select

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's my Oracle (11g) table:

```
--------------------------
|MyTable                 |
--------------------------
|UserID    |Date         |
--------------------------
|1          |4/29/2011   |
|1          |6/13/2013   |
|2          |5/3/2001    |
|2          |2/3/2011    |
|3          |12/3/2009   |
|3          |4/3/2011    |
--------------------------
```

If I perform the following SQL:

```
SELECT MAX(Date) AS upd_dt, UserID 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY upd_dt, UserID
```

I get:

```
--------------------------
|User ID    |Date        |
--------------------------
|1          |6/13/2013   |
|2          |2/3/2011    |
|3          |4/3/2011    |
--------------------------
```

Which I understand. I now want to perform a SELECT on these results and get the row with the most recent date and its userID. Is there a way to SELECT from a SELECT? Something like:

```
SELECT MAX(upd_dt) AS maxdt, UserID 
FROM (    
        SELECT MAX(Date) AS upd_dt, UserID 
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY upd_dt, UserID
     )

GROUP BY maxdt, UserID
```

Comment: why don't you use `where rownum = 1 order by upd_dt desc`??

Comment: @jcho360 It will not work without a subquery

Comment: I'm not talking to make that in the subquery

Comment: In general, you can use a query in place of a table name. In relational theory you can always do that, but in practical implementation there are limits. A table, a view, and the result set of a query are all relations (that's what "relational" refers to).

Comment: @jcho360 as far as I know you have to put the `ORDER BY` *inside* a subquery and the `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` *outside* that subquery. Otherwise you filter before ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your first query should be more like:

```
SELECT MAX(Date) AS upd_dt, UserID 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UserID
```

For your second query, yes you can use subqueries. And I think you don't need to aggregate:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (        
    SELECT Date, UserID 
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY Date dESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
```

Note that you need to put the `ORDER BY` in the *inner* query and then filter with `ROWUM` in the *outer* query. Otherwise what you are doing is `SELECT`ing the first retrieved row (whichever that may be) and then `ORDER`ing that single row. Note also that `ROWNUM` will in general **not** work as you expect unless you restrict filtering to less-than (`<`)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it without subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(Date) AS upd_dt,
       MAX(UserID) keep(dense_rank last order by Date) as UserID
  FROM MyTable;
```

To clarify this part: `MAX(UserID)`. Consider having two rows with the same max `Date` and different `UserID`.

```
--------------------------
|MyTable                 |
--------------------------
|UserID      Date        |
--------------------------
|1          |6/13/2013   |
|2          |6/13/2013   |
--------------------------
```

So you have to decide which one to pick. With that aggregate `MAX(UserID)` or maybe `MIN(UserID)` you can vary the result.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need aggrigation for that? Just order by date desc and select top userid

```
select * from (select upd_dt, UserID from MyTable order by upd_dt desc) where rownum < 2
```

Comment: `rownum` is assigned before ordering, so there have to be subquery.